# ASP.NET: DataList - how to edit 2 vars in Item in ItemTemplate

Tags: .net, asp.net, templates, datalist

I have a datalist, and on the ItemTemplate, I do this for example:

```
<%#Eval ("MinAge") %>
```

Where MinAge is a Int. I also have a MaxAge that is also an int.

Quesiton is, how do i change it so that i could do something like:

```
if (MaxAge == 99)
  MinAge + "+"
else
  MinAge + "-" + MaxAge
```

so that if we have minage=18,maxage=99 it will be 18+
if we have minage=18,maxage=20 it will be 18 - 20

the thing is it gets complicated for me because i try to change int to string, so what is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codebehind do...

```
protected string GetAgeRange(object minAge, object maxAge)
{
   var min = (int)minAge;
   var max = (int)maxAge;

   if (max >= 99)
      return min + "+";

   return min + " - " + max;
}
```

Then replace your

```
<%# Eval("MinAge") %>
```

with

```
<%= GetAgeRange(Eval("MinAge"), Eval("MaxAge")) %>
```

Note the use of = instead of #.

You'll want some more error checking in GetAgeRange but the general idea should be what you need.